How to pool results of type II ANCOVA from multiply imputed data set?
I'm using MICE to impute a small data set. I am going to use ANCOVA of type II through Anova function of R package car. However, I don't know how to pool the results from ANCOVA results from multiply imputed datasets. While I found a reference for ANOVA:

Grund, S., Lüdtke, O. & Robitzsch, A. Pooling ANOVA Results From Multiply Imputed Datasets: A Simulation Study. Methodology 12, 75–88 (2016).

I could not find a reference for ANCOVA.
Question: could you show me a method for pooling ANCOVA results or point me to a reliable reference?

The trick is to pool the point estimates and variance-covariance matrices first, then do the ANCOVA tests on the pooled values.
As explained on this page, ANCOVA is just a particular form of a linear multiple regression model. With respect to Rubin's rules, the same principles apply to ANOVA, ANCOVA, other multiple-regression models, or any model in which the coefficient estimates have something close to a (multivariate) normal distribution. I'd be surprised if the functions built in to the mice package can't handle this directly.
If you want to apply Rubin's rules by hand, it's not too difficult. You need the coefficient point estimates and the variance-covariance matrices from the models on each of the imputed data sets.
You then pool the estimates. The point estimates and the within-imputation (co)variance in a multiple regression follow simple extensions of the formulas for a single parameter. The formula for the between-imputation variance uses the matrix equivalent of the single-parameter formula; see Section 2.3.2 of Flexible Imputation of Missing Data. Summarizing from that reference:
If there are $m$ imputed data sets and $\hat Q_{\ell}$ is the $k \times 1$ column vector of parameter estimates for imputation $\ell$, the pooled parameter estimate $\bar Q$ is the parameter-wise average:
\begin{equation}
\bar Q = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{\ell=1}^m \hat Q_\ell.
\end{equation}
If $\bar U_{\ell}$ is the variance-covariance matrix for the model from imputation $\ell$, the pooled within-imputation variance-covariance matrix $\bar U$ is a similar element-wise average:
\begin{equation}
\bar U = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{\ell=1}^m \bar U_\ell 
\end{equation}
The unbiased estimate of the between-imputation variance is the matrix form of the scalar case, with the "square" of a vector taken as an outer product, the matrix product of the vector with its transpose:
\begin{equation}
B = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^m (\hat Q_\ell-\bar Q)(\hat Q_\ell-\bar Q)'.
\end{equation}
The full combined variance-covariance matrix $T$ is the sum of the within and between matrices, plus a term that accounts for the finite number $m$ of imputed data sets:
\begin{align}
  T = \bar U + B + B/m \\
    = \bar U + \left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)B .\\
\end{align}
Then you perform your ANCOVA (or other tests) based on the pooled vector estimate $\bar Q$ and the pooled coefficient variance-covariance matrix $T$.

mice package could not directly pool outputs from ANCOVA, as far as I know. Also, could you please write down the matrix equivalent of the single-parameter formula. It will be very helpful for me and others.

mice can pool results from lm fits, without pooling the variance-covariance matrices.

@wdg it should be possible to formulate your ANCOVA model as an lm() model, using interactions between fixed effects (if the ANOVA is in more than one dimension) and appropriate modeling of continuous covariates. I've copied the formulas for Rubin's rules in matrix form from FIMD here, as requested. The mice package does that pooling "under the hood."

Thank you for the edit. What would be the degree of freedom for test using $\bar{Q}$ and $T$? I always find it hard to determine the degrees of freedom related to multiply imputed dataset.

@wdg Section 2.3.6 of FIMD explains that. The exposition is pretty clear there (with reference to Section 2.3.5), but it's more involved than can fit nicely into this answer.

Thank you very much. I will have a look later. I wanted to ask more questions, like how to evaluate how good your generalization works in practice, but I think they are out of the scope of this question.
